# How to payment using pre-approved key in Android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have pre-approved key and also confirmed key from Android pre-approval code. My problem is how to pay using pre-approved confirmed key in Android.

Answer (score 1):

The first step in pre-approvals, is on obtaining one from the buyer.

This pre-approval is not tied to any specific seller, but rather to the API caller, and it allows you to make a Pay API call in the future without the buyer having to confirm it.

The pre-approval flow is a separate API call from the Payment flow. In it, you specify the total amount you want to pre-approve, the start and end dates that the pre-approval is valid for, and a few other parameters. (See chapter 8 of the Adaptive Payments dev guide for the full spec: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf )

In this API call, you redirect the buyer to the PayPal site, where he will approve future payments up to the amount you specified. (e.g. if you specified a total amount of $1000, the buyer can make 20 purchases of $50, or 1 big purchase of $1000)

Once the buyer approves this, you have a permission to charge him (In the form of a pre-approval token PA-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, but at this point no money has changed hands.

Now that you have the token, you can proceed to make the Parallel Payment Pay API call, just like you are doing now, BUT you will specify one additional parameter: preapprovalKey=

(And you also need to make sure that actionType is set to PAY )

As soon as you make this API call, because PayPal sees that you have already obtained permission from the buyer (in the form of the approved PA-key), it will immediately move the money to the receivers specified. There is no need for the buyer to be redirected to approve this payment, since he has already pre approved it. (See the logic here?)

So to recap:

Make call to Pre-Approval API, to obtain permission to charge from the buyer
Make call to Pay API (that includes the PA key from step 1) to execute on the permission given.